# Handle of CSV file not Echoing

Tags: php

I've not even messed with this since the last time I used it but it just does not want to run the 2nd echo, Any ideas?

The first echo is fine, it's finding all the names in the specified CSV file, I'm might be being dumb but it just does not like the 2nd echo.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$csvpath="resource/userlist.csv";

if (($handle = fopen("$csvpath", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    $titles = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

    while (($buffer = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",","\"")) != FALSE) {
        $user = $buffer[0];
        echo $user;
        echo '<User Name="$user">
            <Option Name="Pass">password</Option>
            <Option Name="Group"></Option>
            <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
            <Option Name="Comments"></Option>
            <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
            <IpFilter>
                <Disallowed />
                <Allowed />
            </IpFilter>
            <Permissions>
                <Permission Dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\$user">
                    <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirCreate">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirDelete">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirSubdirs">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
                </Permission>
            </Permissions>
            <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">
                <Download />
                <Upload />
            </SpeedLimits>
        </User>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Nevermind, I noticed my mistake.

Comment: If you are using variables within echo must start and end with double quotes so either change your other double quotes to single quotes or escape them.

Answer (score 2):

Variable interpolation does not happen in single quotes:

```
echo '<User Name="$user">....
```

Comment: And if you echo this to a web page, you won't see anything if you don't escape HTML tags. (I don't think you want an HTML output, so try `echo htmlspecialchars('<User Name="' . $user . '">...');`